# Access token warning when logging in using Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using `debug.js` and getting the following message when executing `FB.login`:

> You are overriding current access token, that means some other app is
>   expecting different access token and you will probably break things.
>   Please consider passing access_token directly to API parameters
>   instead of overriding the global settings.

Any clues?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, just started happening recently.

Comment: Having the same issue with npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login. Did anyone solve it?

Answer (score 12):

I solved the issue, the problem was that I was requesting a permission that the app was not approved for, and not using an FB account that was associated with the app in any way.  By adding the user in question as a test user, the problem was solved.  It's rather unfortunate that the error Facebook returns is so completely useless in this case. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue but with other library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login). I am only fetching name and email. I am having this issue even with test user. Somebody else has solved this problem?

Comment: @MustafaMamun I am also having this issue. Any updates on a fix?

Comment: this helps a lot. yes in general facebook has become very useless with their error messages, documentation and review process

Comment: How do you add a test user?

Comment: @jayarjo see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/ - TL;DR: `Open the App Dashboard and choose the app for which you want to manage test accounts. Select Roles then Test Users from the left hand side menu.` . Also, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#roles for how to add existing actual users as testers.

Answer (score 10):

It is probably because you called FB.getLoginStatus followed by FB.login. The error just means that you received an access token the first time when you called .getLoginStatus and then it was overwritten when you called .login.

You can fix this by either removing .getLoginStatus (it is probably unnecessary if you are about to call .login) or instead re-use the access token from .getLoginStatus and pass it to the .login function.

Comment: What if I simply intend to elevate permissions of the app?

Comment: How can you pass the access token to the .login function?

Comment: Why remove `FB.getLoginStatus`? it's a necessary check before calling `FB.login` that would prompt the popup.

Comment: @Karsus you could write it into a variable ? or if you're using React into the `state.accessToken`

Comment: The login function doesn't take an access token argument, you might be basing that answer on an old API version, possibly below `3.0`.

Comment: Definitely ran into this! Ty

Comment: I managed to do this using     `FB.login(function(response=responseFromLoginStatus) {...} `

Answer (score 4):

The real answer is the FB javascript SDK itself has problems, such as the one you reported. You may not be doing anything wrong, the error is probably with FB's SDK (AND / OR with their documentation)

I've reported and documented a similar error at the FB developers community forum, but don't expect a resolution anytime soon.
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/445494736399091/
This happened in Dec 2019, when using Chrome, and the FB JS sdk v5.0

**Update:**
I've since found out there are a few variables involved: For example, when using Chrome, some callbacks are firing multiple times, and returning a different accessToken, and the error message as reported in your question.

When I switched to the Edge Browser, it reported a normal facebook user is not allowed, while the app is in Test mode. wtf? (Chrome allowed my normal fb user). So I created a test user in the developer's dashboard, and when i logged in again, I did not get the error message as reported in your question.

Now, I went back to Chrome, still using my normal fb user (not the special test user), and don't see the error message anymore, or callbacks firing multiple times. (Is this because I gave it sometime to reset itself? who knows !)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have the following:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{tu_id}',
          cookie     : true,
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v3.3'
        });
```

Comment: Please write in English language only.

Answer (score 0):

For us, we missed whitelisting the IP address after migrating the server to a new cloud provider. Updating the IP Address whitelist from Facebook Developer Dashboard:

> Settings -> Advanced -> Security

resolved the issue